# WebDriverException: Permission denied

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I just started learning RobotFramework with Selenium2Library and I can't get to fix an issue on a simple script.

Environment:

- Windows 8.1
- Selenium2Library
- Firefox
- Python 2.7.6

RobotFramework Test Case

```
        *** Settings ***
    Library     Selenium2Library
Resource resource.robot

Send Email
    Open Browser To Login Page
    ${username}=    set variable    mail@hotmail.com
    ${email}=   Set Variable  i0116
    Input Username    ${email}  ${username} 
    ${pw}=      set variable    mypw
    ${pwlab}=   Set Variable  passwd
    Input Password    ${pwlab}  ${pw}
    Submit logiiin
    sleep   5
    Press Key   c_cb0   N
```

in the file resource.robot i have:

```
*** Variables ***
${SERVER}         login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1447686304&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https:%2F%2Fmail.live.com%2Fdefault.aspx&lc=2070&id=64855&mkt=pt-pt&cbcxt=mai
${BROWSER}        Firefox
${DELAY}          0
${LOGIN URL}      https://${SERVER}

*** Keywords ***
Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}



Input Username
    [Arguments]    ${email}     ${username}
    Input Text    ${email}    ${username}

Submit email
    Click Button    next

Input Password
    [Arguments]    ${pwlab}     ${pw}
    Input Text      ${pwlab}        ${pw}

Submit logiiin
    Click Button    idSIButton9

Submit newMail
    Click Element        NewMessage
```

this work loggin but fail new email for send, say this erro:

> > WebDriverException: Message: Permission denied to access property "__qosId" Stracktrace:
>
> at r (https://a.gfx.ms/Share_xgR2IG1nRyxXCDZm4LxGdg2.js:1> 
>    at
>   u/< (https://a.gfx.ms/Share_xgR2IG1nRyxXCDZm4LxGdg2.js:1>

but i not understand why

Comment: which keyword is giving you that error?

Comment: this: `Press Key   c_cb0   N` it is for create new email
print of output in cmd [link](http://prntscr.com/93sj4g)

Comment: This may not be terribly useful for anything more than a possible cause, but I recently updated from Selenium 2.5.X to 3.0.1, going from Firefox 46 to Firefox 49. I started getting WebDriverException: Message: Permission denied to access property "_musculaEventHandlerId" during a Select Window (Selenium2Library) command. So whatever this problem is, it seems to be a Selenium bug.